# cross domain ajax call in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

i am making a small extension to test my apis. But while making ajax calls it throughs error.

```
 Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8080/acton-demouser/user1?callback=jQuery2210009971836116164923_1456851818933&format=json&_=1456851818934' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

while my ajax call url was :
    http://localhost:8080/acton-demouser/user1

manifest.json :

```
{
  "name": "Ajax Helper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon.png", "128": "icon.png" },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

js file :-

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var ajaxType = $('#request-method-selector option:selected').val();
    var urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:8080/acton-demo';
    var url = $('#url').val();
    if(ajaxType === 'GET'){
        $.ajax({
            url: (urlPrefix+url),
            error: function() {
                    $('#error').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
                },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                        $("#success").html(data);
                    },
            type: 'GET'
        });
    }

});
```

what i am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the 'http://localhost:8080' to the content_security_policy definition as a whitelist. Because you're using the 'jsonp' as a dataType at calling your endpoint with $.ajax. That is, it is not Ajax calling, but it is a script tag creation. Therefore, you have to add the domain to the content_security_policy definition.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:8080 https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
```

Basically, we can specify URLs which has a 'https' prefix only. However, for easy development, it allows us to specify two domains 'http://localhost' and 'http://127.0.0.1'. This is described in the [document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing).